# drop down menu align in a single line

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu

I have made three drop down menu. I want to align one after the other. Below is the code I am using. But its not coming in the same line. What I want is first should go on left, second should go on center and third should go on right.

First is

```
<div style="float:left;">
<FORM name="mapform" method="POST">
<SELECT name="jump" size="1">
<OPTION value="" SELECTED>Select the Category</option>
<OPTION value="http://www.fe dri.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=1">Ask a Question</option>
<OPTION value="http://www.fe dri.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=4">Vehicle for Sale</option>
</SELECT>
<INPUT type=button onClick= "location = '' + document.mapform.jump.options[ document.mapform.jump.selectedIndex ].value;" value="Place an Ad!">
</FORM>
</div>
```

Second is

```
<div style="float:center;">
<FORM name="mapform2" method="POST">
<SELECT name="jump2" size="1">
<OPTION value="" SELECTED>Select the Category</option>
<OPTION value="http://www.fe dri.com/discuss">General Discussion</option>
</SELECT>
<INPUT type=button onClick= "location = '' + document.mapform2.jump2.options[ document.mapform2.jump2.selectedIndex ].value;" value="Quick View !">
</FORM>
</div>
```

Third is

```
<div style="float:right;">
<FORM name="mapform1" method="POST">
<SELECT name="jump1" size="1">
<OPTION value="" SELECTED>Select the Category</option>
<OPTION value="http://www.fe dri.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=16">Start New General Discussion</option>
<OPTION value="http://www.fe dri.com/posting.php?mode=post&f=28">Start New Event</option>
</SELECT>
<INPUT type=button onClick= "location = '' + document.mapform1.jump1.options[ document.mapform1.jump1.selectedIndex ].value;" value="Start a Discussion!">
</FORM>
</div>
```

I am getting it as in the image

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is no `float:center`. Float your first two divs left, and the last one right. This should fix the problem, assuming you have enough space for all your elements on one line.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/MCRUX/

In case you missed it in the example, I have set the width of each of the container divs to `30%`:

```
<div style="float:left;width:30%;">
```

Comment: :) then wht to use... ? and how to achive it.. i dont know more code

Comment: @user1820652 Like I said, use `float:left`. I've added a demonstration.

Comment: Your correct asad, but still there is some problem I think its the width issue. My width is 990 px. can u tell me the how to place it.

Comment: @user1820652 Set the width of each to be `30%`, like I have demonstrated in my example.

Comment: yes i Have done with 30%, the button of last is falling below the line

Comment: @user1820652 That is because the button is too long. Either make smaller buttons or make a wider page.

Comment: cant we play with the width to adjust it?? by seeing the page we can say all three can adjust easily..

Comment: @user1820652 Try setting the width of the last div to 40%.

Comment: yes I got it now if I set last one 40%. But there is a gap after the last button to the end of the page

Comment: @user1820652 Set the width of the dropdown to 50% and the button to 50%. Also, this is unrelated to your original question, which I have already answered

Answer (score 1):

Use a table having 3 columns to align the drop down box.

```
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="left">{drop down box 1}</td>
    <td align="center">{drop down box 2}</td>
    <td align="right">{drop down box 3}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: shivan, do you means; I have to place my first, second, and third code inside of each bracres ???

Comment: yes, you should place the code within the place holder ( the curly brackets )

Answer (score 0):

As @Asad said, there is nothing called **float:center**. If the size of the parent element in which you are placing your divs has a fixed size, you can do some mathematical calculation and decide the size of the divs you are gonna place.

for example, if i have a parent box of **960px** and want to place 3 divs inside it, i ll do something like this...

```
div.children {
width:313.33px;
margin-right:10px;
float:left;
}

div.children:last-child {
margin-right:0;
}
```

Since **313.33 X 3 ~ 940** plus total margin will be **20px** and both will add upto 960px.

Comment: I am having 990 width can u tell me how to add all here ??